# Reference to a rotated image in latex

Tags: graphics, cross-referencing, rotating

I've inserted a rotated image in my document, rotating the caption as well.

```
\begin{figure}[H] 
\begin{adjustbox}{addcode={\begin{minipage}{\width}}{\caption{CAPTION.
  }\end{minipage}},rotate=270,center}
  \includegraphics[scale=.7]{IMAGE.png}%
  \label{fig:workflow}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{figure}
```

The problem occurs when I try to write a reference to this image:

[image]

If I click on the reference on the output, it works and sends me on the image, but question marks appear instead of the image number. How can I fix this issue?

Thank you all!

Comment: Put `\label` right after the `\caption` command before `\end{minipage}`.